# For any integer $n$, show that $7n+1$ and $15n+1$ are relatively prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For any integer $n$, show that $7n+1$ and $15n+1$ are relatively prime.

From the Euclidean Algorithm,\begin{align*} \gcd (15n+1,7n+1) & =1 \\
15n+1 & =7n+1+8n.
\end{align*}Hence,$$\gcd (15n+1,7n+1)=\gcd (7n+1,8n).$$To finish, I have to show the above expression equals one. Again by the Euclidean Algorithm,$$7n+1=q(8n)+r.$$If I keep going, I end up making it longer or most likely in an endless loop.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137461/discussion-on-question-by-drmichaelmorbius-for-any-integer-n-show-that-7n1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is to first eliminate $n$. Consider that the greatest common divisor $d$ is also a divisor of
$$
15(7n+1)-7(15n+1)=8
$$
but at this point you're doomed, because for $n=1$ you have
$$
7n+1=8,\qquad 15n+1=16
$$
But, if you add the condition that $n$ is even, then $7n+1$ is odd and, since $d$ must also divide $7n+1$, we have $d=1$.

---

For odd $n$, the gcd can be $2$, $4$ or $8$. We've already seen the last case. For $n=3$ we have
$$
7n+1=22,\qquad 15n+1=46
$$
For $n=5$ we have
$$
7n+1=36,\qquad 15n+1=76
$$

Comment: So it is only valid when n is even? otherwise n as odd is false correct?

Comment: @DrMichaelMorbius Yes: when $n$ is odd, both $7n+1$ and $15n+1$ are even.